# spring xd dlq configuration parameters

Tags: spring-xd

I have set up a spring xd  stream with DLQ and I have made cyclic configuration to
 return  from DLQ to main Queue.

```
 xdbus.s3Test.0-->DLQ-->xdbus.s3Test.0 

stream create s3Test --definition "aws-s3-source | log" 

stream deploy S3test --properties module.*.consumer.autoBindDLQ=true
```

To make it a circle I had to change the configuration of  DLQ  adding this  manually from rabbit mq ADMIN UI .

```
x-message-ttl:  30000
x-dead-letter-exchange: Default(Empty)
```

Is there any way in spring xd I can configure DLQ properties?Because DL queue will be  generated by XD at run time and Ideally I cannot tamper this in production.Can i set some properties to set the above properties for DLQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the DLQ properties through XD, but you can create a policy in RabbitMQ that applies to DLQs created by XD:

```
$ rabbitmqctl set_policy XDDLQTTL "xdbus\..*\.dlq" '{"dead-letter-exchange":"", "message-ttl":30000}' --apply-to queues
```

This applies your required properties to all queues starting with `xdbus.` and ending with `.dlq`.

I just tested it with this and it works nicely...

```
xd:>stream create ticktock --definition "time --fixedDelay=60 | transform --expression=1/0 | log"
Created new stream 'ticktock'
xd:>stream deploy ticktock --properties module.*.consumer.autoBindDLQ=true
Deployed stream 'ticktock'
```

And you can see the message cycling (because of the divide by zero).

One caveat - this will keep trying forever; you would need some code in the module to look at the `x-death` header if you wish to abort after some number of retries.

Comment: Thanks Gary You saved the day :)